# How to implement rmsle metric in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, metrics

I want to implement rmsle metric in tensorflow. But instead I have loads of errors or if I implement it as a loss_function it just gives NaNs

**Here are NaNs if I use it as loss**

[image: With NaNs]

Here is if I use it as metric

[image: If Use metric]

Train and Test split ***doesn't have NaNs***

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K


def rmsle(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.exp(tf.cast(y_true, tf.float64)) - 1 # convert from log(RMSLE) to RMSLE
    y_pred = K.exp(tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float64)) - 1
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(K.log(y_pred + 1) - K.log(y_true + 1))))

n_features = X_train.shape[1]

model = Sequential([
Dense(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_features,), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)),
Dense(150, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)),
Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)),
Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)),
Dense(1)
])

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='mse', patience=100, verbose=1)
model.compile(loss=rmsle, optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0000000001), metrics=[rmsle] )
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=64,validation_split=0.2,callbacks=[early_stop], use_multiprocessing=True)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
```

Comment: What kind of dataset are you using?This code is working correctly when I tried with Image dataset for binary classification. There might be problem with the dataset preprocessing.